# "Пока она подкачивает, к сожалению"

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Возможно ли так сказать? Если нет, то тогда вообще слово *подкачать* в настоящем времени нельзя употреблять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нельзя. Дело не в грамматическом времени, а в том, что у глагола совершенного вида "подкачать" в данном значении нет парного несовершенного вида. Вариант *подкачать-подкачивать* годится только для прямого значения - "добавить чего-либо методом качания или качки". Или для разговорного "немного качает, укачивает". А вот для "не подкачал" в значении "не подвел" только это самое "не подводит" и годится. Или что-то близкое по смыслу.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus!